# Creating new post in Wordpress via REST API - how to past meta title and description for Yoast SEO plugin?

Tags: wordpress-rest-api, yoast

I'm creating new post using wordpress rest api. On the WP side, there is Yoast SEO plugin used, where I would need to update meta description and meta title fields through API calls. Is there any way how to send this data?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this wp plug-in : https://github.com/ChazUK/wp-api-yoast-meta

```
{
  id: 123,
  ...
  yoast_meta: {
    yoast_wpseo_title: "Testy Test | My WordPress site",
    yoast_wpseo_metadesc: "My description",
    yoast_wpseo_canonical: "http://my-wordpress-site.test/testy-test"
}
```